# What are the benefits of enabling restore points on non-system drives?

Tags: windows, system-restore

I don't really understand what enabling System Restore for non-system drives does.

I have it enabled on `c:\`, my system drive, and off for my other two drives.

On `d:\` some user folders like documents and pictures are kept, as well as some programs.
[image: User folder redirect]

On `e:\` I have a bunch of programs.

What would enabling restore points on those drives do for me?

Comment: Based on the answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/350427/138343), I don't think it would do all that much for you.