# Intermittent Wireless Loss

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet-connection, wireless-card

I'm currently using a Windows 7 HP Pavilion DV6TQE with a Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1030 card. I've recently encountered a problem where every 2-15 minutes, I will suddenly lose internet connection. My computer still shows that it's connected to my router, but any attempt to access a webpage result in it just loading for all eternity. Oddly enough, the only solution that I've found is to disconnect and reconnect to any network (even the same one). This causes me to regain connection, only to repeat the problem again in a few more minutes. I've reinstalled the drivers several times to no avail. Additionally, whenever I boot into Ubuntu (dual-boot), I have perfect connection, and have never encountered a problem, leading me to believe that this is not a hardware issue. If anybody has any advice, I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: how often does this happen? and by any chance have you tried restoring your system to an earlier stage where the problem wasn't there?? Also, if you're re-installed using the existing drivers via device manager, have you tried to re-install from a fresh download?

Comment: @AzkerMohamed The problem occurs in bursts. These bursts can last hours, and the connection loss within these bursts usually happens every 2-15 minutes, sometimes even less. However there can easily be a couple hours between these bursts, where it seems like the problem has fixed itself, usually after restarting my computer or waking it from sleep. Also, in terms of drivers, I have restored my drivers using device manager, and I have also downloaded fresh OEM drivers from HP several times, to no avail.

Comment: @AzkerMohamed Unfortunately, as the problem has been increasing in frequency over time, I never thought to restore my system until recently. For a while I would only get a burst every few weeks to a month, but now it happens every hour or so when I'm on my Windows 7 boot. But to restore to before it first ever happened would take me back the better part of a year, and the amount of data backup that I would have to go through certainly makes this a last resort.

Comment: System restored will restore back to the date you choose, but DATA's won't be effected as I assume. You may refer to "[What does Windows System Restore exactly back up and restore?](http://superuser.com/a/350427/241326)" to know what it exactly restores. I'm still thing how it works well in Ubuntu but not Windows. There is something went wrong withing the system.

Answer (score 0):

Most laptops have a bay on the bottom where the wireless card is placed. The wireless card is a rectangle, roughly 1.5 in by 2.5 in with two antenna wires connected with mini BNC (cable-tv style) wires.  My first step would be to double check those connections to make sure one of the antennae didn't come loose or disconnected.  Finally, I would remove and reseat the network card.  If all of these fail after the computer is turned back on, I would perform a system restore.  As a last resort, a full system wipe (after backing up your data of course).