# Multiple programs run to issues after an instant shutdown on a blue screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, crash, bsod

Jump to Update 3 for a quick view of problem details and cleared list.

---

**Issues found so far**

1. Apache(httpd) won't start, a crash happens always with "stackhash_0a9e" error
2. Closing Notepad++ throws an exception notification, and the process isn't closed at background

Both programs are running when crash happened.

**About the windows crash**

It's normal to my laptop, though I never knew the cause (I tried to find out once before, but no luck after wasting a lot of time searching, reading and playing with some debug softwares), but it works for me forcing it to shut down on blue screen and then restart, every time. In short, I believe whatever the cause of the windows crash is, it shall not be the cause of the issues in question.

**Any changes to windows before it crashed?**

No, I was coding and testing on my local website as usual, and no actions happened at the exact time it crashed because I was thinking on a problem. It just crashed as before, and I was ready to press the power button.

**What I've done**

At first I searched for the error message of starting apache and tried to figure out what's that, but then I realized it shouldn't be apache when there's no file or configuration changes.

Worried of bad disk sectors, I ran a disk check on driver of apache resides, no bad files, no bad sectors found

**Guess the cause**

As Issue 2 appears, I began to think it's something wrong on my windows, and if there's a difference between this crash and past crashes, I was in a hurry to back to my work and pressed down the power button too fast, I'm afraid my windows shut down before the blue screen throwing out its last line, and I suppose there's some work in the background interrupted by the shut down? What is that and how to fix it if possible?

Any advice?

---

**Update 1**

Run a system driver check, a couple different lines than the other driver check, it shows:

- 2 EA records processed
- 69 reparse records processed

I don't know what's that mean

**Update 2**

- Found a restore point of several hours before the crash happened, but problem remains after restore.
- Re-installed Notepad++, issue gone first, but appear again later
- Re-installed apache, problem remains
- Run SFC, no problems found
- Scan Registry and fix issues, no use
- Add httpd to DEP exception, no use

**Update 3**

Problem details

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: httpd.exe
  Application Version:  2.2.22.0
  Application Timestamp:    4f242d7a
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_0a9e
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   00000000
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 01f2a689
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Cleared List

- System files check OK
- hard drivers check OK
- Memory Diagnostics Tool standard check OK
- registry check OK
- Apache(httpd) files and configure OK
- DEP exception add OK

But Apache still crashes, notepad++ closing issue occurs from time to time, any suggestion on what to check next?

Comment: Just found the answer of http://superuser.com/questions/343112/what-does-windows-system-restore-exactly-back-up-and-restore is very useful to diagnose my problem

Answer (score 1):

Try and run a SFC scan

1. Go to start menu and type in cmd. Run it as admin.
2. Enter `sfc.exe/scannow`
3. Wait till it is finished then reboot

Comment: Have tried that, no use.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a BSOD (especially many) has not been caused by damage to operating system files & applications is pretty brazen. Since you don't really have any evidence otherwise, the first suspect should be those crashes. Until the crashes are ruled out, Ignoring them as a possible cause or symptom of your issues is a waste of both your time and ours.

I recommend you re-install Windows 7 Ultimate (I'm assuming that's what you have based off your crashdump), as it seems this is where the problem is coming from. If you have a retail disc/image or a patched OEM image, you can also do a [non-destructive repair install.](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html)

Comment: There are 22 crashes in the past year before this one, none damaged the system, I think this can be a base, not for generic cases, but for my windows. On the other hand, assuming the particular one crash did damage the system, due to the fast shutdown, there is no dump file created, if you know other methods to handle the crash, please let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately re-install windows is not an option for me with a tight project schedule. While I do consider in-place upgrade as the final measure, with all those checks I've done to narrow the scope, guess I am already close to the issue, maybe just one more place to check.

Answer (score 1):

These random crashes are usually related to memory issues.
I'd recommend downloading the free memory testing software ['memtest'](http://www.memtest86.com/).
Follow instructions from site.
Burn the ISO and run it for a few hours.
This at least will let you know if your memory sticks are ok and could possibly solve the problem completely.

Comment: I have used Windows Memory Diagnostics Tool to check memory, the result of a standard test is ok, do I need to run an extended test which looks very slow, or as you said to use the third-party 'memtest' instead?